# How to create PasswordCredentials object and pass in New-AzADApplication using Azure PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I want to create Azure Active Directory Application with PasswordCredentials. The following doc uses Password and not PasswordCredentials https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadapplication?view=azps-2.4.0

Could anyone suggest how do i create PasswordCredentials object using Az module and pass in the `New-AzADApplication`

```
New-AzADApplication -DisplayName "xxx" -IdentifierUris "xxx" -PasswordCredentials
```

Comment: From the type name, I'd guess [`New-AzureRmADSpCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermadspcredential?view=azurermps-6.13.0)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  New-AzADApplication is part of new Az module and not AzureRM and for new scripts i am using Az so this won't help

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43079255/9898643) can help?

Comment: @Theo if you look into the code its using New-AzureRmADApplication and i have mentioned in the question and comments that I need Az example not AzureRM so that link won't help

Comment: I meant just the part where the `PSADPasswordCredential` is created. Skip the last 4 lines

Comment: @Theo it then complains Cannot find type [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.Models.ActiveDirectory.PSADPasswordCredential so how do i reference this namespace in powershell when using Az commands

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
$passwordCred = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.PSADPasswordCredential]@{ 
    "StartDate" = [DateTime]::UtcNow
    "EndDate" = [DateTime]::UtcNow.AddYears(1)
    "Password" = "{password-here}"
}

New-AzADApplication -DisplayName "My_app" `
                    -IdentifierUris "https://example.com/api" ` 
                    -PasswordCredentials @($passwordCred)
```